# How to map a response(key value pair) to post request URL in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, http, data-binding, string-interpolation

In angular I have sent a http get request whose response is as follows:

{
"name1":"id1",
"name2":"id2",
"name3":"id3"
}

Now I have mapped this response in the select field of my reactive form, this drop down shows the list of names I am getting from the above response. ( For eg. name1, name2, name3)

Now the requirement is, I have to submit this form to a URL where the id should be dynamically selected according to the name I select from the select field in my form.

(For eg if I select **name1** & hit submit button then the post request should be sent to "http://url/**id1**")

How can I map the response of the get request to my url for the post request to be sent ? Please help, thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 0):

You already use name1, name2,... as options on your dropdown. So why do you not use id1, id2,... the same way as option values? On submit you can get the value of the dropdown field and call a url with it.

If your problem is something else please explain it more specifically and provide some of your code.

Answer (score 0):

In your api service create the post method:

```js
     serverUrl = "http://url/"
    
     sendPostRequest(id: string, body : MappedObject): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.post(this.serverUrl + id,body );
      }
```

In your component.ts:

```js
   postForm!: FormGroup;
  
        constructor(private _apiService: ApiService,private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}
        
          ngOnInit() {
          this.postForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            name1: [''],
            name2: [''],
          });
  
        }
        
        
ngSubmit() {     
 

this._apiService.sendPostRequest(this.postForm.controls.name1.value,this.postForm.value).subscribe(
            (res: any) => {
              console.log('Success');
            },
            (error) => {
              console.log(error);
            }
          );
        }
      }
      }
```

```
When you click on submit button, call the ngSubmit() method
```